# How to get the value of the checkbox lable in material-ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Checkbox from material UI. This is the import statement:

```
import Checkbox from '@mui/material/Checkbox';
```

I have the following code being rendered :

```
<Checkbox value="Tutor 1" onClick={() => handleSendSelection()}/>
```

I want to get the value of the selected checkbox inside the handleSendSelection() function. When I print the value, it gives me undefined, whereas my expected value is the string "Tutor 1".
How should I get the value of the checkbox?

```
const handleSendSelection = (event) => {
   console.log("value - ", event.target.value);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";


export default function App() {

  const [value, setValue] = useState("")

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="checkbox" value={value} onChange={() => (setValue("tutor_1"))} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can do something like that try to make an controlled checkbox qand set it according to your choice

Answer (score 2):

You did not pass the event in onclick function.

```
   <Checkbox value="Tutor 1" onClick={(event) => handleSendSelection(event)}/>
    const handleSendSelection = (event) => {
      console.log("value - ", event.target.value);
    }
```

Here's the working sandbox code
https://codesandbox.io/s/checkboxes-material-demo-forked-4xo59?file=/demo.js